# How does order by row id work in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, rowid

I have a table called points. I executed the following query and expected a list of lexicographicaly sorted list of ROWIDs but that did not happen. How does Order by rowid sorts the row?

```
select rowid from points order by rowid
```

I had rows like following

1. AAAE6MAAFAAABiSAAA
2. AAAE6MAAFAAABi+AAA

2nd row is lexicographicaly smaller than first row. So what is sorting criteria if it is not lecxicographical sorting?

Comment: It is a pseudocolumn. There's no sorting criteria, so you shouldn't rely on these IDs. More over, these IDs could change, if you would move your table, for example. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Comment: That second affirmation is not entirely true. `2nd row is lexicographicaly smaller than first row.` For the oracle database it would depend on some NLS database settings.

Comment: Basically you shouldn't use `rowid` for ordering, there is no possible scenario I can think of that will be useful to order by `rowid` for it

Comment: Of course there are scenarios where order by ROWID is useful. If you don't have unique key and you still want deterministic order. Oracle sorts by ROWID internally within non-unique index just because of the same reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why you see is only a representation used for display purposes.

The actual rowid contains binary information about the data block, the row in the block, the file where the block is located and the internal object id of the table ([See the manual for details](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998))

When you use `order by rowid` Oracle sorts the rows based on that (internal) information, not based on the "string representation".

If you change your query to:

```
select rowid, 
       dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(rowid) as rel_fno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_row_number(rowid) as row_num,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as block_num, 
       dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid)
from points 
order by rowid
```

You will most probably see the logic behind the ordering of the rownumber.

Note that the value for `dbms_rowid.rowid_object()` will always be the same. And if you only have two rows in your table, both will most probably also have the same value for `rowid_block_number()`

Comment: I'm saving my votes on answers for later trying to pursuit a gold badge, but couldn't help not voting for this deeply detailed answer! :)

Comment: This is a really good answer.  But, do you have any idea why the string representation doesn't preserve the original ordering?  It shouldn't be that hard to make a string representation that does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry, no Idea. I *guess* the string representation is just concatenating hex values - but maybe not in the same order as the individual elements are used for comparison.

Comment: It's concatenation of base-64 encoded bytes (object id, [file number if small file tablespace], block number, record offset)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of rowid is not guranteed. It depends on how you have set the NLS settings. Also rowid represents the  physical allocation of the row in the database. A rowid is considered immutable(does not change) but if you delete a row and insert it again then it changes.

> If you delete a row, then Oracle may reassign its rowid to a new row
>   inserted later.